# Transformation on a composite system in terms of transformation on the individual basis vectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two Hilbert spaces: $\mathcal{H}_1$ with the basis $\{| 0 \rangle_1, | 1 \rangle_1 \}$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ with the basis $\{| 0 \rangle_2, | 1 \rangle_2 \}$, and I have a unitary $U$ acting on the composite Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$. Can I find a unitary $U^{'}$ acting on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1 \oplus \mathcal{H}_2$ spanned by the basis vectors $\{ |0 \rangle_1, | 1 \rangle_1, |0 \rangle_2, | 1 \rangle_2 \}$, such that the action on the composite Hilbert space is equivalent?

In other words, given an operator $U$ in $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$, find $U^{'}$ in $\mathcal{H}_1 \oplus \mathcal{H}_2$ such that

$$
\begin{bmatrix} |0 \rangle_1 \\ |1 \rangle_1 \\ |0 \rangle_2 \\ |1 \rangle_2 \end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow 
U^{'} \begin{bmatrix} |0 \rangle_1 \\ |1 \rangle_1 \\ |0 \rangle_2 \\ |1 \rangle_2 \end{bmatrix}  \implies \begin{bmatrix} |0 \rangle_1 |0 \rangle_2 \\ |0 \rangle_1 |1 \rangle_2 \\ |1 \rangle_1 |0 \rangle_2 \\ |1 \rangle_1 |1 \rangle_2 \end{bmatrix} 
 \longrightarrow U \begin{bmatrix} |0 \rangle_1 |0 \rangle_2 \\ |0 \rangle_1 |1 \rangle_2 \\ |1 \rangle_1 |0 \rangle_2 \\ |1 \rangle_1 |1 \rangle_2 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

---

***[Cross-posted on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28461/55)***

Comment: In general $U$ would be an element of $U(4)$ acting on your composite $H$, but your $U’$ would be an element of $U(2)\otimes U(2)$, which is only a subgroup of $U(4)$.  Thus not all $U$ can be written as $U’$’s.  However, your diagram suggest you are actually given $U’$ and want to find $U$?

Comment: I am want to find the U' which will enact the U. But why would all $U^{'}$'s be of the form you wrote?

Comment: Take a look in $\color{blue}{\textbf{Example A}}$ of my answer here [What is the symmetry of the pion triplet (π−,π0,π+)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420080/what-is-the-symmetry-of-the-pion-triplet-pi-pi0-pi).

Comment: More generally take a look about **Product Spaces** and  **Product Transformations** in my answers here [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).

Comment: As long as you don't specify what the relation between a vector in $\mathcal H_1\oplus \mathcal H_2$ and $\mathcal H_1\otimes \mathcal H_2$, your question is underspecified and cannot be meaningfully answered.

Answer (score 0):

After digesting Norbert Schuch's comments plus reading the OP carefully again plus reviewing some old notes I have to convert the previously accepted answer to a long comment:

- We know that the "one-particle", aka single qubit, Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ describing only spin up/down is spanned by $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ and may be identified with $\mathbb C^2$. The two-qubit Hilbert space can therefore be viewed as  $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ which is spanned by all Kronecker products of two complex two-vectors, i.e., by all matrices
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}\varphi_1\psi_1&\varphi_1\psi_2\\\varphi_2\psi_1&\varphi_2\psi_2\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\psi_1,\psi_2\in\mathbb C\,.
  $$
- As a vector space $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ is obviously isomorphic
  to $\mathbb C^4=\mathbb C^2\color{red}{\oplus}\mathbb C^2\,.$ However,
  $\mathbb C^4=C^2\color{red}{\oplus}\mathbb C^2$ with its canonical scalar product
  $$
  \langle \mu,\nu\rangle=\overline{\mu}_1\nu_1+\overline{\mu}_2\nu_2+\overline{\mu}_3\nu_3+\overline{\mu}_4\nu_4
  $$
  is *not* the right Hilbert space to describe the two-qubit system.
- The right scalar product for $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ starts with the definition
  $$\tag{1}
  \langle \varphi\otimes\psi,\mu\otimes\nu\rangle:=\langle\varphi,\mu\rangle\langle\psi,\nu\rangle=(\overline{\varphi}_1\mu_1+\overline{\varphi}_2\mu_2)(\overline{\psi}_1\nu_1+\overline{\psi}_2\nu_2)
  $$
  for product states which can be linearly extended to all states of
  $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ since they are linear combinations of product states. The fact that we norm all single qubit states to one is also important to make the scalar product well defined.
- To see that $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ with (1) is the right Hilbert space, and not $\mathbb C^2\color{red}{\oplus}\mathbb C^2\,,$ consider
  three qubits. Their Hilbert space is -as we know-
  $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ which is eight-dimensional and not six-dimensional like $\mathbb C^6$.
- To make a long story short, the coincidence that
  $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^2\color{red}{\oplus}\mathbb C^2$ (as a vector space) led me to formulate the below answer which does not really address your issue.

Previous answer:

If you identify each Hilbert space ${\cal H}_i$ with $\mathbb C^2$ then ${\cal H}_1\otimes {\cal H}_2$ will become isomorphic to $\mathbb C^4$. A unitary $U'$ that acts only on ${\cal H}_1$ would be a matrix
$$
U'=\begin{pmatrix}u_{11}&u_{12}& 0 & 0\\ u_{21}&u_{22}&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
If you compose this with a unitary $U''$ that acts only on ${\cal H}_2$ you will end up with

$$
U''U'=\begin{pmatrix}u_{11}&u_{12}& 0 & 0\\ u_{21}&u_{22}&0&0\\ 0&0&u_{33}&u_{34}\\0&0&u_{43}&u_{44} \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
It is clear that not every unitary $U:\mathbb C^4\to\mathbb C^4$ can have this form.

In the language of tensor products: $U(2)\otimes U(2)$ is only a subgroup of $U(4)$ as mentioned in ZeroTheHero's comment.

Comment: Unitaries on $\mathcal H_1\oplus H_2$, as mentioned in the question, need *not* be of this block-diagonal form. Indeed, the spaces of unitaries on the two spaces *are* isomorphic (as the spaces are isomorphic).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch . How would a complex $4\times 4$-matrix look like that leaves ${\cal H}_2\equiv\mathbb C^2$ invariant ? An extra phase multiplication that does not change the state is all I can imagine.

Comment: How would a 4x4 matrix act on a vector in $\mathbb C^2$?

Comment: $\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^2$ is a four-dimensional vector space, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb C^4$. This allows every linear map on the tensor product to be viewed as a $4\times 4$-matrix.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch . I think I see a point now but it is late. Will reconsider from scratch tomorrow.